# Show that projection onto a subspace is unique even with a different basis.

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-writing

Let the columns of $A$ and and the columns of $B$ span the same subspace $S$ (ie $A$ and $B$ have the same column space).

Show that $A(A^TA)^{-1}A^T = B(B^TB)^{-1}B^T$, that is show that the matrix that projects onto $S$ is unique independant of your choice of basis.

Comment: We can prove this geometrically if we define the projection in any manner independent to our matrix formula.  This does feel like the line of proof they're looking for given the question statement, though.  Any thoughts on how you're supposed to approach this?  For example, should we be using $QR$ factorization or something?

Comment: There is some basis for the containing space in which the projection matrix is of the form $\left(\begin{array}{c|c}I&0\\\hline0&0\end{array}\right)$. The first $\dim S$ elements of this basis are a basis for $S$. What happens to this matrix when you change this first part of the basis?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We can prove this geometrically if we define the projection in any manner independent to our matrix formula.  That being said, we can prove the statement with matrices too.

We note first that the formula only applies if the columns of $A$ and $B$ are linearly independent, so we can assume that $A$ and $B$ have a number of columns corresponding to the dimension of the columns space (that is, $A$ and $B$ both have full column-rank $n$).  We note that $A$ has the same column space as $B$ if and only if there exists an invertible matrix $C$ such that $B = AC$.  That is, $A$ has the same column space as $B$ if and only if there are column operations that take us from one matrix to the other.

With that being said, we have
$$
B(B^TB)^{-1}B^{T} = \\
(AC)((AC)^T(AC))^{-1}(AC)^{T} = \\
AC[C^TA^TAC]^{-1}C^TA^T = \\
ACC^{-1}(A^TA)^{-1}C^{-T}C^TA^T =\\
A(A^TA)^{-1}A^T
$$
So, the projection matrices are indeed the same.

Comment: Much more straightforward than my idea.

Comment: @amd essentially the same, though